# Form POST using Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring

I am developing a simple web page using bootstrap/javascript as frontend and what I'm trying to do is to send out a HTTP POST to reach my backend (I used Spring as backend) but I get 400 Bad Request.

I have the following script and HTML and I'm trying to pass form id to function below to perform HTTP POST.

// script on  tag
      function sendData(data) {

```
      alert('Data' + data);
      var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var urlEncodedData = "";
      var urlEncodedDataPairs = [];
      var name;

      // Turn the data object into an array of URL-encoded key/value pairs.
      for(name in data) {
        urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[name]));
      }

      // Combine the pairs into a single string and replace all %-encoded spaces to 
      // the '+' character; matches the behaviour of browser form submissions.
      urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');

      // Define what happens on successful data submission
      XHR.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
      });

      // Define what happens in case of error
      XHR.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
        alert('Oops! Something goes wrong.');
      });

      // Set up our request
      XHR.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/api/novoCondomino');

      // Add the required HTTP header for form data POST requests
      XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      // Finally, send our data.
      alert('urlEncodedData' + urlEncodedData);
      XHR.send(urlEncodedData);
    }

    </script>
```

// Form HTML code

```
<FORM NAME="myform" id="inputform" onSubmit="JavaScript:sendData(inputform)">
     <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="inputAddress">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="condomino" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Apartamento</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apto" placeholder="Apto">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Senha</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send "class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

When I hit button to submit the form, I get 400 Bad Request Error. I know this is wrong because it seems I'm sending HTMLDocumentElement as payload instead of JSON object. I have found some solutions without Javascript but turns out my backend won't accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded so I want to set content type to application/json. POST works fine when using POSTMAN when passing JSON object as data.

How can I fix my code using Javascript solution to send out data from form exactly as my backend expects (some DTO class as below)

//DTO class expected by backend
    public class UserCommand {

```
    public UserCommand() {

    }

    private int apartament;
    private String name;
    private String password;
```

//Controller at backend side

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(value = "/novoCondomino"
)
public User createUser(@RequestBody UserCommand newUser)
    {

    return usrService.createUser(newUser.toUser());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

> POST works fine when using POSTMAN

Do you mean that you are using a JSON body in Postman and that it's working?

If so, the solution would be to ensure you are using a properly formatted JSON when you call `XHR.send()`.

Log what you pass to `XHR.send()` and POST it using Postman, if you get a 400 there you'll know for sure. If I misunderstood anything let me know.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. I think i'm passing invalid data from form... I logged what I'm passing to XHR.send and that would be
0=%5Bobject+HTMLInputElement%5D&1=%5Bobject+HTMLInputElement%5D&2=%5Bobject+HTMLInputElement%5D&3=%5Bobject+HTMLInputElement%5D&4=%5Bobject+HTMLInputElement%5D&acceptCharset=&action=http.... I removed some string as it's clearly html code which is wrong. I don't know how to pass json object from form

Comment: @AndréRamos Simply create a JavaScript object (ex.: `body = { name: "andré" }`) and pass it in `XHR.send(body)`.

Comment: Thank you @Hacène

I could prepare the request by using getElementById for getting each field data and then pass the JS object as you said.

var nome=document.getElementById("condomino").value;
var apto=document.getElementById("apto").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
body = {"nome": nome, "apto": parseInt(apto), "password": password };
XHR.send(JSON.stringify(body));


Marked as accepted answer. Thanks.